# android splashcreen weird when quitting

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have created a splashscreen for my android app. I went down the route with an activity of it's own displaying itself in a splashthread and then loading the "MainMenu" acitivty.
This works alright, until I want to quit the app.
When I hit the "back button" I see the MainMenu window. When I hit the "back button" a second time .. I don't see the splashscreen I see the MainMenu once more. An additional "back" will end the app.

Not nice, are there any good hints on how to avoid that behaviour?
 Best of all would of course be to end the app directly when hitting "back" form the "MainMenu" but I guess I then need to re-model the splashscreen to be a part of that activity instead?

Splashcode

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          try {
             Log.d("Trying","Tries");
             int waited = 0;
             while (waited < 5000) {
                sleep(100);
                waited += 100;
             }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              Log.d("Catching", e.toString());
          } finally {
             finish();
             Intent i = new Intent(UEABB.this,MainMenu.class);
             UEABB.this.startActivity(i);
             startActivity(i);

          }
       }
    };
    splashThread.start();
 }
```

Regards

Comment: btw, shouldn't you call finish after `startActivity(i)`? That is async, so I'd first fire the intent and then call finish()

Comment: your probably right, I'll try that for sure ;)

Comment: Nope, I moved "finish()" after the startActivity(i) call, no difference. I still need the extra "back" to actually exit the app, annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to explicitly set the `android:noHistory="true"` on the SplashScreen Activity in your manifest.xml. I followed a similar approach when designing my "What's New" Activity.

```
<activity android:name=".activities.WhatsNewActivity"
    android:label="Version History" android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Nevertheless you should call `finish()` once you switch to another activity.

Comment: yes afer starting another activity from this splash screen he should have closed this one finish(). think this alone will solve the problem no need of android history

Comment: "no history" tag didn't make any notable fierrence, I think I'll just have to live with that extra "back" or rewrite the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

Your splashthread activity should call `finish()` immediately after starting the MainMenu activity. That will remove it from the stack and it shouldn't interfere with exiting the app.

Unless you are consuming the back key in an event handler, I can't think of anything else off the top of my head that could cause this behavior. Perhaps you could post the code for splashthread.

Comment: I added the code, I do call the finish and I don't interfere with the "Back" button anywhere. Weird..

Comment: Could this be because the splashcreen activity is the first one in the app? I can't think of any reason, it's all done by the book of Google as far as I can see.